# How to set NavigationNode AudienceIds

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

In a recent CSOM update by Microsoft [(see here)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/project/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-sharepoint-online-july-2018/), the AudienceIds property of the NavigationNode has been made public

I've been trying to set an Audience for the node using Powershell but so far no luck.

First problem is that property requires a list of Guids and users/groups don't have guids, just integer ids. There's associated guids for them in the User Information List, and i've been trying to set them as so

```
$r = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[Guid]"
$guid  = [Guid]"366d271a-4cc1-40e1-8449-c2f7b622b245"
$r.add($guid)
$node = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id 2066

$node.AudienceIds = $r
$node.update()
$context.executeQuery()
```

This apparently fails quietly, as no error is given, and no audience is applied.

Has anyone gotten anything done using this property?

Comment: the REST api throws an exception when attempting to pass an array, with the error that a "StartObject" was expected, but no idea what properties need to be passed in that object.  Have you found any more info? '_api/Web/Navigation/GetNodeById(2082)' '{
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.NavigationNode"
},
"AudienceIds":{"958d7612-9513-4aa8-8da4-8bb48106e85e"}
}'

Comment: The REST command appears to successfully save the value using the following format for a collection of GUIDs, but as you have noted, does not appear to actually change any visibility/functionality: `{
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.NavigationNode"
},
"AudienceIds":{"results": ["958d7612-9513-4aa8-8da4-8bb48106e85e"]}
}`

Comment: I have also set the `Web.NavAudienceTargetingEnabled` equal to `true` and am using the guid of an Audience created in User Profile Managed in the SharePoint Admin Center.  Still does not seem to take affect.

Comment: @oaden, Is there any update on this? Have you resolved this?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm able to update the audience IDs like @willman has but it has no affect on visibility.